# How to add max-width to all images in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way to have all images automatically include a max-width so that they can never be bigger than their native resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is a way... with CSS, if you are using i.e. Twitter Bootstrap 3+ just add the class `img-responsive` to all your images (via TypoScript or with JavaScript line at the bottom).

You can just also use this definition in your stylesheet, just make sure it's not overridden later by TYPO3 (check it with browser inspector tools):

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of using max-width instead of just width. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A handy way to add en extra class to all your images is to use *fluid_styled_content* instead of *css_styled_content* and then overwrite the default fluid template partial.

If you want to try it set the following using the constants editor in your root template record

```
styles.templates.partialRootPath = any/path/to/your/partial/folder
```

then copy the file *MediaGallery.html* from *typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials* to your partial folder. Now TYPO3 uses your MediaGallery.html partial file for rendering and you have the freedom to change anything in the rendering there. For example:

```
<f:media file="{column.media}" class="img-responsive{f:if(condition: data.imageborder, then: ' img-thumbnail')}" width="{column.dimensions.width}" height="{column.dimensions.height}" alt="{column.media.alternative}" title="{column.media.title}" />
```

adds the class *img-responsive* to all images and if you selected a border for the image in the backend it will also add the *img-thumbnail* class.

You may also want to have a look to the following constants:

```
styles {
    content {
        textmedia {
            # maximum width of generated images
            maxW = 920
            # maximum width of generated images (beside text)
            maxWInText = 400
            # column spacing in pixels for multiple image columns
            columnSpacing = 10
            # row spacing in pixels for multiple image rows
            rowSpacing = 10
            # spacing to the text
            textMargin = 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a mixture of fluid and non-fluid sites so this is very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Images are not upscaled during processing. If they appear bigger than their native resolution you should check your styles.

Comment: Yes I know, but in a responsive layout you need to set the width as a percentage, therefore you also need to stop it getting bigger than its native size.

Comment: I just want to add style="max-width:[native width];" to all img tags